# Slow printing with label printer could be caused by my software?

Tags: delphi, printing, reportbuilder

I have a software that prints labels. It generates many pages with n columns to be printed in a label printer (commonly Argox or Zebra). I use report builder to do so, meaning I send the jobs through the windows driver and not directly to the printer.

I have this one customer that is having a really hard time printing her labels. The printer pauses for 15-20 seconds between one page and another.

I´ve reviewed each and every configuration I could and did not find anything.

To make my problem worse, my customer uses the Bartender software (wich comes with Argox) and when printing there it has not this delay. Bartender uses the windows driver as well.

Well, from the point of view of my client, the problem is with my software, I don´t blame her.

From my point of view I can´t control such a thing (pause between pages) once I am using the driver.

Am I wrong? Is there anything I could do to avoid such a delay?

Important Info

- Argox OS 214 TT - PPLA
- Drivers updated to the last version (7.2)
- Serial Cable being used

Comment: No answers here, just troubleshooting angles...   It acts like it's waiting for more output. Maybe the printer, or the windows driver, doesn't know if you're done sending the page and waits for a timeout?  There may be a printer setting that governs the behavior.  I'd also try (and have her try) printing to a PDF driver like the free CutePDF and see if that also pauses.

Comment: Suggest you to use printing directly to the COM port. It's fast as lightning :) Forget the drivers...We printed receipts and coupons through drivers first and it was ok. Then we decided to send commands directly to the COM port and it was good decision.

Comment: Print to file with your software and other one, and compare?

Comment: @evilone Even in an environment where I have to print in many printers (Zebra, Argox, etc), many labels with tiny diferences do you recommend to use the commands? Is the learning process slow or the commands are straitforward to learn? thanks

Comment: Commands can be different by printer brand. We implemented ESC/P commands and used same command set with different printers. No problem occured so far. Not so hard to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the report software you use create ZPL output, or a bitmap? You can check this by setting your printer driver to print to a file. If the file is huge, >1MB, it's probably creating a bitmap and that could take a long time to send to the printer.

Bartender would create ZPL if using internal fonts and barcodes, so the output will be tiny and the printer is optimized to print native ZPL. If your software uses fonts not on the printer (Arial, Times new roman, etc), it will send the label down as a graphic instead of using the printer's built in fonts, which would result in a HUGE file even for a small amount of text. Same thing goes for graphics, inlined vs. recalled graphics

Comment: I am accepting your answer as it was determinant for me. I just recommended my client to switch cables from serial to parallel and the delay disappeared. Although for the long run I will consider to make my software generate ZPL command. Thank you very much.